# Pass (Angular ) array to Rails form field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, forms

I've got a Rails/Angular app where, on an edit page, I do some processing of a textfield input. I then want to pass the result to another (invisible) textfield, which is part of a Rails form. The result of the processing is an array and looks like the following, after being passed to the (normally invisible) textfield.

[image: Rails form field]
When I now send the form, I get the following error in the backend (the backend is waiting for a array to process):

```
undefined method `each' for "[\"mvsdjfs\"]":String
```

To me it seems like, because I'm sending the content of a textfield, it's being sent as a string. What's the best way to send this as a array? Thanks!

Comment: You should update your hidden filed to match as `'abc', 'def', 'ghi'` without `[]` and ruby will read it as array or call `.split(',')` on your string if it doesn't

Comment: Then I get this error: `undefined method each for "mvsdjfs":String`

Comment: `c = "mvsdjfs"` then `c.split(',') => ["mvsdjfs"]`

Comment: If there is no `,`, the string stays a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
2.1.5 :016 > c = "one, two, three"
 => "one, two, three" 
2.1.5 :017 > c.split(',')
 => ["one", " two", " three"]
```

From question comments:

> If there is no `,` the string stays a string?

You'll need at least some element to split by, and this element you need to add with javascript when you update the hidden field.

```
2.1.5 :018 > c = "one/ two/ three"
 => "one/ two/ three" 
2.1.5 :019 > c.split('/')
 => ["one", " two", " three"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a helper method like this and will add it as an answer if it helps someone but will accept your answer as you pointed me into the right direction :)

```
def something
  array_i_fy(params[:contact][:labels]).each do .....
end

def array_i_fy(object)
  return object.str.split(',') if object.class == Array
  [object]
end
```